# SQL CASE statements and MINUS

Tags: sql, oracle, types, case

Is there something about CASE statements that automatically breaks a query that uses MINUS? I'm comparing a live pull of a data set to a previous cache of it, and even though the CASE statements in the live pull return pure VARCHAR2 results, I get a type mismatch between them and the static values in the cache table, which are stored as VARCHAR2 as well.

The only other possibilities I can think of are even less likely - could concatenations ( || ) or literals in single quotes, both of which are present in the CASE results, be fouling things up?

Comment: A sample of your query including your CASE statement should help us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your SELECT statement, do you have any more fields except this CASE? MINUS tries to compare the entire rows, maybe some of the other values aren't matching.

Did you try trimming the case ( `TRIM(CASE foo WHEN..` ) to see if you slipped anything?

Are all the branches returning VARCHAR2? Sometimes, even if one branch returns a number or a date, it could mess up the types.

Comment: Well, one of the branches of each statement is a URL cobbled together like so:

Comment: 'literal text string' || CHAR_VALUE || 'literal text string' || NUM_VALUE || 'literal text string' (is there any way to insert line breaks in a comment)    But even slapping a TO_CHAR on the NUM_VALUE, or on the whole thing, or both, doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Well, funnily enough, I tried putting TO_CHAR on both the NUM_VALUE and the whole branch again, and this time it worked. And yeah, I'm going to have to figure out a way to give meaningful examples of what I'm doing online without posting anything that could be linked back to the employer-proprietary elements of what I'm working on (which is to say, all of it).